# Spring Controller for PDF download, location.href,jQuery Modal and and IE8 headers

Tags: jquery, spring, internet-explorer, pdf, download

I have a simplistic Spring MVC controller method to return a PDF :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/attachment/portfolios/{investorNum}/reports/{reportId}/periods/{reportingPeriod}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]>  getReportForDownload(@PathVariable String reportId, @PathVariable long investorNum, @PathVariable long reportingPeriod) throws IOException{
        InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/sample.pdf");
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        //headers.setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/pdf"));
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        headers.add("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=abcd.pdf");
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(IOUtils.toByteArray(in), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

And a spring bytearray message converter :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
       <property name="messageConverters">
         <util:list>
                <bean id="byteArrayMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
         </util:list>
         </property>
    </bean>
```

And a jQuery modal box for download :

```
"Download" : function() {
 location.href = "./attachment/portfolios/2201/reports/DELINQSUM/periods/1137";
}
```

The download button works fantastically fine in FF, Chrome but not in IE. IE says

> Internet Explorer cannot download 1137 from localhost.
>
> > Internet Explorer was not able to open this Internet site.  The
> >     requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found.  Please try
> >     again later.

I followed headers as in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316431 and [2](http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/internet-explorer-was-not-able-to-open-the-internet-site-the-requested-site-is-either-unavailable-or-can-not-be-foundplease-try-again-later/) but nothing happens and IE continues report the problem.

Also, I am streaming the PDF for embedded display inside the modal with the below change and that works fine :

```
headers.add("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=abcd.pdf");
```

I am running this on a tomcat.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem. I'm generating a PDF with Apache FOP and writing it to the response in Spring manner with the same headers you have and `ResponseEntity`.
I solved the problem by choosing `HttpStatus.OK` instead of `HttpStatus.CREATED` in the `ResponseEntity` constructor.

Obviously IE8 doesn't understand a 201 (CREATED) as response code.